# ADF SQL Linked Service Connection is failing

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am receiving following error when I click on test connection in the linked service. Linked service is configured using a self hosted integration runtime. IR is up and running without any issue. What could be the reason for this?

Connection failed
Cannot connect to SQL Database: 'xxxxxxx', Database: 'xxxxx', User: 'xxxx/xxxx'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
The operation completed successfully
Activity ID:

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have mistakenly used forward slash instead of backslash for the user name

Comment: @PratikSomaiya Yes

Comment: that's great, happy to hear that :)